# Legal obligations if an employee obtains a rival company's strategy

Tags: united-kingdom

If I were a manager for a tech company, and one of my employees had obtained a commercial in-confidence document detailing a rival company's strategy for bidding on a contract my company was also bidding on, what would I be legally obligated to do under UK laws?

Answer (score 1):

Legally, the employer is responsible for the actions of the employee. So your company "obtained" it in the eyes of the law.

How it was "obtained" matters.

1. If it was obtained through criminal means then there may be obligations to report the employee to the police. For example, in New South Wales, it is a crime to fail to report a serious indictable offence: theft, computer fraud and corruption would all be serious indictable offences.
2. If it was received in confidence then it is confidential information and its use would be the tort of breach of confidential information. For example, an employee of Company A told an employee of Company B the information in circumstances where the Company B employee knew or should have known that it was given in confidence; something like "Don't tell anyone but ...".
3. If it was "obtained" innocently, for example, by finding it in the other company's garbage or lying by the side of the road; then you can use it.

Notwithstanding, it has clearly compromised the tender process and if you used the information and won the contract, this may be sufficient to make the contract voidable.

Comment: I could imagine that to submit bids, you'd have to declare that you are not aware of any competitors' bids.